# Accessing website hosted on iis from different network

Tags: iis

I have hosted a site on iis on my laptop. And i can access it from my local machine(cpl-akshay.com). Now if my friend try to access this site or if i try to access this site through mobile then the browser is not able to access this site.

Error after accessing site through mobile or from outside my network: "The webpage is not available"

I tried turning off firewall or creating inbound rule.!

[Inbound Rule screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTYfC.png)

Comment: What url does your friend use to try and access the site?

Comment: @BrandonSpilove same url i am using to access through local machine i.e. cpl-akshay.com

Comment: If your friend tries to ping cpl-akshay.com, does it respond with your IP address? If not, he'll have to add a dns or host entry for it.